# I need recommendation on books for Talim

Tags: quran, hadith, fiqh

I want to do Talim in my house(with my wife and child). Please note that I am not an Alim, rather a regular Muslim. I need recommendation on books which are

1. Good for Talim
2. Use Sahih Hadith (At least mention these are Sahih Hadith and these are not)
3. The interpretation must be according to the way Sahabah (ra) & Salaf understood it.
4. If it talks about a masail, it must mention that the masail is derived from these Ayat of Quran and these Sahih Hadith

Just to mention, I do not want strictly academic books but books with fazail. So that my family will know Allah and will be interested to do amal.

Comment: What is  or what do you mean by "talim"?, note that book recommendations always are somehow opinion-based and can end up too broad.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Talim means To educate; to bring or train up. http://hamariweb.com/dictionaries/nurture_hindi-meanings.aspx

Comment: Please don't consider terms you know as known or understood by the reader and try explaining them by a few words: ta'lim is an Arabic term (or at least derived from the Arabic term) for teaching masail -in Arabic-  is the plural of the Arabic term mas'alah and usually means case study and is in first place related to fiqh issues. The mostly advised hadith compilations for ta'lim don't fulfill your 2nd point, as both 40 of an-Nawawi and riyad as-Saliheen  of the same author or even Jami' al-U'lum wal Hikam include weak ahadith as well.

Comment: @Medi1Saif are Jadul Maad, Buloogh al-Maraam good books for Talim in house?

Comment: Zaad-u l-Ma'ad is a book of ibn Qayyim (a hanbali scholar and student of ibn Tayymiyah) and it includes seera, fiqh and the practice of the prophet pbuh, bulugh al-Maraam is a book of ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani (the shafi'i scholar whom call him sheikh al-Islam and commentator of al-Bukhari and author of fath al-Barry and many other books on hadith sciences) the book basically provides ahadith on fiqh issues. None of these books include only sahih narrations, as shafi'i's and more explicitly hanbali's rely on hadith and prefer da'if hadith to any none textual source in fiqh matters

Comment: List questions are [not appropriate for Q&A sites](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/), and may be considered as [off-topic](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13961). While there is nothing inherently wrong with such questions, they tend to be subjective or opinion-based, not specific enough as a new answer could always be added, and not constructive, as every answer may be equally valid.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh,

here are my suggestions

For Aqeedah (basic tenets of faith): 
1)Thalaathat al-Usool
2)Al-Qawaa’id al-Arba’ah 
3)Kashf al-Shubahaat

For Hadeeth:

1)Fath al-Baari Sharh Saheeh al-Bukhaari, by Ibn Hajar al-‘Asqallaani (may Allaah have mercy on him).
2)Subul al-Salaam Sharh Buloogh al-Maraam, by al-San’aani, and his book Jaami’ bayna al-Hadeeth wa’l-Fiqh
3)Nayl al-Awtaar Sharh Muntaqaa al-Akhbaar by al-Shawkaani

Comment: I do not want a strictly academic books but books with fazail. So that my family will know Allah and will be interested to do amal.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest some books which are recommanded by Ahlul Sunnah Community.

I am giving the link bellow so that if they update the list, it is also updated here.

[Important books for the seeker of Islamic knowledge](https://islamqa.info/en/14082)

Please also read the following article. At the end it has some book recommendation as well.

[How to seek knowledge](https://islamqa.info/en/20191)

I would like to add two more article specially about books.

[How should a Muslim deal with books of knowledge?](https://islamqa.info/en/10690)

[We do not advise you to continually read the books of the people of misguidance](https://islamqa.info/en/92781)